# OpenLayers add interaction select and translate

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I want to add select and translate interaction by using something like addInteraction function. I know I can do something like this

```
const select = new ol.interaction.Select({});

const translate = new ol.interaction.Translate({
   features: select.getFeatures(),
});
map = new ol.Map({
   interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([select, translate]),
   target: 'map',
   layers: layersCollections,
   view: view,
});
```

But I don't want to add this interaction when I create map. I want to add them after I create the map. How can I do that?

Comment: `map.addInteraction(select); map.addInteraction(translate);`

Comment: It works here https://codesandbox.io/s/translate-features-forked-kiblj